# Find Jordan Form if $A^2$=$E$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Find Jordan Form of $A$ if $A^2$=$E$
>
> $E$ - Identity matrix.

I was wondering how can I find characteristic polynomial from this conditions. Or probably there is a 'special' solving way, never met such tasks before.

Couldn't find a way or a tip on the internet too.

Comment: What is $E$? The identity matrix?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick yes

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The information does not determine the Jordan normal form of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the polynomial
$$
p(t)=(t-1)(t+1)
$$
annihilates $A$. It follows that the minimal polynomial $\mu_A(t)$ must divide $p(t)$. In particular, this implies that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$. Moreover, the largest Jordan block for any eigenvalue has size one, since the minimal polynomial splits into linear factors. This implies that the Jordan form is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{diag}{diag}
\diag(\pm1,\dotsc,\pm1)
$$

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot! Just forgot about minimal polynomial properties, now it's clear.

Comment: I would not quite say that the minimal polynomial divides this "by definition"; the statement ostensibly follows from the Euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'd say it depends on one's definition of the minimal polynomial. A common one is as the unitary generator of the ideal of annihilating polynomials, in which case it is true "by definition."

Comment: @quid never seen it, but I guess I can buy it. Of course, the polynomials over any field are a PID

Comment: This is the definition of the minimal polynomial I have in my head but it's probably not the definition most linear algebra students have in theirs.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(A-E)(A+E)=A^2-E=0$. What can you say about the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Comment: $λ mod Amin $==0,
where λ - characteristic polynomial?

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. The other answer has it right.

Comment: thank you a lot for response, you are 100% right too, but Brian added a lot of details, that helped me to understand your idea, thanks.

Comment: @GD I am glad you got what you're looking for